Should a 10 speed shifter only click 9 times?
The LTwoo shifter I bought (the elite version of the a7) is a 10 speed but only clicks 9 times. Should it be 10 clicks?

What is a7? Could you please point to the exact  model of what you bought?

There are 9 transitions between 10 gears.  Think about it this way; you started in a gear, and then changed to 9 more, for a total of 10.

If you're in gear 1, to get to gear 10 you add 9.

This is called a fencepost problem

This might help https://youtu.be/seP2DPqd0o8?t=70

Imagine you have only two cogs in the rear. You start on the smaller one. If you downshift once (down means larger cog, up means smaller one), you're now on the bigger cog. That was one click. You had two cogs.
By extrapolation, a mechanical rear shifter will have have one fewer detent than the number of cogs.
I'm not sure how MTB front shifters did it, but road front shifters will have trim positions, so there are multiple clicks despite there being only two chainrings. MTB front shifters were probably the same way. I realize there are still some two chainring setups, especially among modern hybrids.

You have to be in a gear to start with, you don't start in zero gear, you start in one, now how many increases to get to ten? The first increase would bring you to 2nd gear; extrapolating to tenth gear, there should have been 9 increases. So there are nine gear changes to go from one into ten.
If that's not clear enough point to your thumb on your left hand. That's your starting position, now count each finger after the thumb, so the index is one position increase, middle is two, ring finger is three, and finally, your pinky is the fourth. So there's always one less transition than there are gears. So ten gears, nine clicks. Simple right?
